# Pull data from multiple Excel sheets and count specific items

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question and I think the answer should be fairly simple, but I cannot get it figured out.

We have an Excel spreadsheet where we track out leads. My boss wants to know, specifically "how many leads for each month and how many of each source and the result."

I want to put the formula in a separate sheet in the same workbook; meaning, I need a formula that pulls the data from a specified range of cells in a different sheet, and counts how many leads we had in a specific month (12012, or 22012).

I've tried variations of the following:
='Sheet1'!(=COUNTIF(e2:e20,"12012"))
='Sheet1'!counte2:e20
and the sum function, vlookup, and basically every other programming answer I could come across on multiple forums where the question was even remotely close to what I am trying to do...

I think the problem is getting it to pull from the different sheet, but I can't figure out how to make my formula work correctly.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: `And the sooner the better!!` It doesn't work like that in stackoverflow. Try Freelancer.Com or Elance.Com?

Comment: FYI: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Personally, I don't have an issue with the attempt, as he listed a couple of things he tried and its a pretty straightforward answer as well.  Although the last line isn't useful for getting people to help.

Comment: Sorry for the faux pas on posting in a forum like this. This is my first time ever needing to ask my question, since I can normally find the solution to my problem based on other answers. I think the people who post in here with answers are very knowledgeable and have an understanding of Excel far beyond mine, which is why I decided to post here instead of one of the other sites. So any help at all would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A14:A21,12012)

Comment: That formula works brilliantly! As long as I don't try to use it in Google's version of Excel. Got it to work correctly in Excel, copied the formula into my Google Drive document and got a "parse error" message. Fortunately, other people have this same problem, put quotes around the sheet name and it works perfectly. Thank you for your help!